# How to style div tag based on content?

Tags: html, css

I want to create div tag based on size of content inside it. I have created a message box and inside it there is a message text. When the text is less eg: Hi, hello then the div tag should align itself and should not leave too much space on right side.

Code:

```
<div className="msgBox"><p className="msgText">{message.message}</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.msgBox {
    background-color:   #EBEEFD;
    border-radius: 25px;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.msgText {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

So my final goal is to have message box size based on the text content inside it. If content is small then small box large content then large box.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can't do that with CSS. the only thing you can do with css is to style empty tag or tag with content. For this you'd need to determine several classes styled differently and set classes with JS depending on content length, like `.short, .medium, .large`

Comment: To be clear you are looking for a variable width?

Comment: @amflare I want to create size of div such that it automatically resizes based on the text inside it how can I do that ?

Comment: @extempl I want to create size of div such that it automatically resizes based on the text inside it how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the assigning the background color to `msgBox` assign it to the text and make it a `display:inline-block` to have the width of its content

```css
.msgBox {
  max-width: 150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.msgText {
  background-color: #EBEEFD;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="msgBox">
  <p class="msgText">Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="msgBox">
  <p class="msgText">What are you doing?</p>
</div>

<div class="msgBox">
  <p class="msgText">What are you doing in this chat application?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `className` here is from React.

Comment: `className` could be from angular or React or some other framework it is not the issue